# Multi-dispatch to candidate with native parameters not working

Tags: raku, rakudo, nativecall

I am trying to use `multi` in my Raku code that wraps a function in `C`.
Here I am calling `lchoose` function in shared libray `Rmath`.
This is my code which *works*:

```
use NativeCall;

constant RMATH = "./Rmath"; # shared library
sub lchoose(num64, num64) returns num64 
        is native( RMATH ) { * };

# The C function signature is 
# double    lchoose(double, double);

sub r_lchoose($n,$r) {
        return lchoose($n.Num, $r.Num)
}

say r_lchoose(9,8) # 2.1972245773362196
```

But this does not work. The code keeps on *running/hanging*. Neither *dies* nor throws any *output*:

```
use NativeCall;

constant RMATH = "./Rmath"; # shared library
multi lchoose(num64, num64) returns num64 
        is native( RMATH ) { * };

multi lchoose($n,$r) {
        lchoose($n.Num, $r.Num)
}

say lchoose(9,8) # Neither dies nor throws any output
```

My expectation is when I call `lchoose(9,8)` it should call second multi as the arguments are definitely not `num64`. If it had used second function, then it would have called the first function and given the output.

Or atleast I expected the program to throw error rather than hang.

#### OS information

Windows 11 64-bit

#### Raku information

```
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2022.04.0000.1.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.04-3-ga9fcd5a74.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `num64` in a signature indicate that it **MUST** have a `num64` for a multi dispatch to work.  Otherwise you could not set up candidates for a `Num:D` *and* have a candidate for `num64` or `num32`.

And because there is no candidate for `Num` in your example, it will dispatch back to the original candidate, causing the infiniloop.

I would therefore write the "catch-all" lchoose candidate as:

```
multi lchoose(Num() $n, Num() $r) {
    lchoose(my num64 $ = $n, my num64 $ = $r)
}
```

In the signature we convert everything to `Num`, and then we assign these to nameless native `num64` variables in the call the other candidate (which will now dispatch correctly).

Comment: What does `Num()` does in function signature `multi lchoose(Num() $n, Num() $r)`? Is it that whatever comes as `$n` or `$r` are converted to `Num` before proceeding?

Comment: Indeed.  `Num()` is short for `Num(Any)`, which means: accept `Any`, and coerce to `Num`.  For instance: `my Num() $a = 42; dd $a;  # 42e0`.  It's also called a [coercion type](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-Coercion_type)

Comment: Wonders if the call to ```lchoose(...)``` could be ```nextwith(...)``` - would this  suppress the infiniloop?

Comment: I suggest you try?  :-)